# Decoding several variables from a slot in contract

Tags: solidity

There are 3 variables in one slot(number2) in my contract:

```
  uint8 private flattening = 10; //2
  uint8 private denomination = 255; //2
  uint16 private awkwardness = uint16(block.timestamp); //2
```

This is the data that I receive from getstorageAt():

```
Slot 2 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008430ff0a
```

I know how to decode it with 1 variable, but I can't find how to do it with several uints.I tried to do this :

```
value = "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008430ff0a"
    
y = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(["uint8","uint8","uint16"],value)
console.log(y)
```

And I got an error:

```
const error: any = new Error(message);
                           ^
Error: data out-of-bounds (length=32, offset=64, code=BUFFER_OVERRUN, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

I'm sure that these 3 variable are in my 2nd slot:

```
  bool public locked = true; //0
  uint256 public ID = block.timestamp; //1
  uint8 private flattening = 10; //2
  uint8 private denomination = 255; //2
  uint16 private awkwardness = uint16(block.timestamp); //2
  bytes32[3] private data;//3-4-5
```

Maybe I need to slice this bytes32 somehow? Thanks for your help.

Comment: where are you assigning `const: error` ? can you post it?

Comment: You should first try with decoding only two uint8 values. Just to be sure as to what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `ethersjs` does not yet know how to decode packed data.

You can check this thread here: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2373

`web3js` cannot do it either.

Solidity has a function to encodePacked, but does not have a function to decode packed data. Check here: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/6919

It seems it's not that easy to create a tool that can decode packed data dynamically. Check: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode

If you know the data, you could try decoding it yourself.

For example, your data is practically `0x8430ff0a`. It has 4 bytes. The smallest values `uint8` are put at the end, and the biggest value `uint16` is put at the beginning.

So 10 is `0a` in your data. 255 is `ff`. And the `uint16(block.timestamp)` is the rest: `8430`. Knowing this you could try to implement a logic in js to decode it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Now I know how to do it manually)