# solidity decode packed data

Tags: solidity, uniswap, uniswapv3, encoding

uniswap creates paths in the following way:

```
ISwapRouter.ExactOutputParams memory params =
    ISwapRouter.ExactOutputParams({
        path: abi.encodePacked(WETH9, poolFee, USDC, poolFee, DAI),
        recipient: msg.sender,
        deadline: block.timestamp,
        amountOut: amountOut,
        amountInMaximum: amountInMaximum
    });
```

I have a function accepting packed data as bytes, how do I read the data back out I've tried the following but It doesn't work with packed data

```
(address inputToken, uint24 fee, address outputToken)  = abi.decode(swapResolverOptions.path, (address, uint24, address));
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no tool to do that at the moment. This is what the documentation says: `Since the encoding is ambiguous, there is no decoding function.`.

Check the docs here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode

I have answered a similar question before, take a look to get an idea on how to try to decode this data if you know exactly the types: [Decoding several variables from a slot in contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/141333/decoding-several-variables-from-a-slot-in-contract/141343#141343)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** this is only for decoding path, and is not a general solution if you want a more general solution you can parse out the length of your data type by the offset using this [bytes lib](https://etherscan.io/address/0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564#code#F34#L11)

This can be decoded using uniswaps Path library

```
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/Path.sol';
```

then declare using for bytes:

```
using Path for bytes;
```

Then you can decode using the library methods:

```
(address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint24 fee) = swapResolverOptions.path.decodeFirstPool();
```

Comment: Maybe worth adding this is working for this very precise use-case and is by no mean a general solution to decode abi.encodePacked data, as OP's title mention

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth I've updated it

Comment: I've also Included info on how to parse using the slice method.